# Handle a 3-tier Application Development with Scrum and Jira

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

I want to manage a `3-tier Application` Develpoment (Data/Business/Presentation) with `scrum` in `jira` but do not know if I use 3 Projects (one for each Layer) or one project and arrange the layers with the `epic` tag function.

I have found a lot about big scrum projects but not with this structure and the most articles refered to big teams that we do not have.

Comment: What if the tiers are Components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with tools is that they will attempt to drive your adoption of scrum. I advise stepping away from the tool and considering how you see the approach when simply using scrum. Then see whether the tool will model that.

For the situation you describe, I would think about one product and one product backlog, with multiple product backlog items.  The product backlog items would describe vertical slices of functionality that cross all three tiers of your business model

Answer (score 0):

It is unusual when using the Scrum framework to break out the tiers of the application in to separate projects. With Scrum we typically work on user stories that represent vertical slices through an application that deliver some business value.

Separating out the tiers means that:

- You create external dependencies, which makes it difficult for teams to resolve their own problems. The Scrum Guide includes the following: "Cross-functional teams have all the competencies needed to accomplish the work without depending on others not part of the team."
- Measuring the rate of progress of 'done' software becomes more difficult. The Scrum Guide says: "Incremental deliveries of “Done” product ensure a potentially useful version of working product is always available."
- You create a synchronisation and resourcing problem in that the teams have to work at a balanced velocity so that they build the three tiers at a consistent rate. For example, the business tier development mustn't get too far ahead of the presentation tier.
- Testing may be less effective as you have integration testing that spans several teams. This makes coordination more difficult and it may increase the time between when the code is written and when bugs are revealed.